# Insert data with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a form to insert data to database with jQuery, but there's no action happen and want to know where the problem is.

Here's the code I wrote, and I hope someone will help me find where the mistake is, and why there's no action on it.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="insert.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form-search" method="post" action="index.html">
<input name="gov" id="gov" type="text" class="textinput required" maxlength="80" required><br>

<input name="area" id="area" type="text" class="textinput required" maxlength="80" required><br>
<button id="submit" type="button">insert</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

insert.js code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var gov =$('#gov').val() ;
        var area =$('#area').val() ;
        $.ajex({
        type   :'post' ,
        data   :{gov:gov,area:area},    
        url    :"insert.php",
        success :function(result) {
            alert(result);
            }
        })

    });
    });
```

insert.php code

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

if($_REQUEST['gov']) {

    $gov=$_REQUEST['gov'];
        $area=$_REQUEST['area'];
$q="inser into gov values ('','$gov','$area')";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$q);
if($query){
    echo "data insert " ;
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Look at your browser's developer console.  Is there an error?

Comment: Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to solve it yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you discovered when you debugged your code, so we can help.

Comment: You should take a look at your browser's console. Theres's probably an error in your code. For example, you wrote `$.ajex(`, but it is `$.ajax(`.

Answer (score 0):

This script (with your html) will submit the data (with console logs to the browser) to 'insert.php'. Please read the comments for explanations. If it still doesn't work, the problem probably lies in your PHP code (I don't work with PHP). The ajax is sending the data to 'insert.php', which should be coded to accept the data variables and return a json response back to the ajax function in the script.

```
// Remove the 'e' from .ready and place in the 'click' function - this is the 'event'
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        // Stops the form from being submitted 'normally' (to index.html)
        e.preventDefault();

        // Check console in your browser (this can be removed when it works)
        console.log('submit clicked');

        // Define the data to be submitted with the ajax form
        var submitData = { gov: $('#gov').val(), area: $('#area').val() };

        $.ajax({

            // Make sure your path to insert.php is complete - check console in browser to see if there is an error
            url: 'insert.php',
            // Make sure 'insert.php' accepts 'post' transactions
            type: 'POST',
            // This could be changed (when it works) to - data: { gov: $('#gov').val(), area: $('#area').val() },
            data: submitData,
            // Make sure 'insert.php' returns a json result
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {

                // This can be removed when it works
                console.log('ajax success');

            },
            beforeSend: function () {

                // This can be removed when it works
                console.log('ajax beforeSend');
                // This can be removed when it works - this lists out the data submitted with the form
                $.each(submitData, function (index, value) {
                    console.log('index: ' + index + ' value: ' + value);
                });

            },
            complete: function () {

                // This can be removed when it works
                console.log('ajax complete');

            },
            error: function () {

                // This can be removed when it works
                console.log('ajax error');

            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: i did what you said but no thing happened

Comment: @Mohamed Bayoumi - I've updated the answer, which should cover the ajax side

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Networks' tab using the Developer Tools. Check if there's something happening when you press the submit button. Check for a status code.